# How can I apply conditional formatting to rows that get added to a pivot table when it is refreshed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have pivot table in an Excel workbook that summarises information from a table in the same workbook. I have applied Conditional Formatting (data bars) to the pivot table. I have added `Year` & `Month` fields to the Rows of the pivot table so that I can summarise data per month.

Each month goes by and I refresh the pivot table yet the conditional formatting does not get applied to the row that gets added for the new month.

Hence over time I end up with a pivot table that looks like this:
[image]

Is there a method of ensuring that conditional formatting rules get applied to rows that get added to a pivot table in the future? Failing that, can I retrospectively modify the conditional formatting rule to apply it to the new rows? I have tried messing about with the "Applies to" part of the Conditional Formatting rule, but to no avail thus far.

I'm using a Mac by the way but I don't think that's relevant. The features I'm talking about here seem consistent with Excel on Windows that I have used in the past.

---

An answer below suggested checking the "Preserve cell formatting on update" option but unfortunately that option is already checked

[image]

Comment: Your question was linked from [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1775107/how-to-make-my-pivottable-into-a-heatmap-persistently). You may have already figured it out, but the solution I posted seemingly works for that particular case.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try that

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort this out by removing the existing conditional formatting and applying it again, including all the new rows this time. Obviously this isn't preferable so I am hoping that Rajesh's suggestion works when I refresh the pivot table on 1st August.

Comment: ,,, reapplying CF on regular basis is the tedious job,,, especially  when you are working with large data set to the option,, Preserve the Format,,,, & Refresh PT is technically correct & useful too. ☺

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repeat everything on a [new question posted today](https://superuser.com/questions/1775107/how-to-make-my-pivottable-into-a-heatmap-persistently), see the solution to see if that works for you. Basically, edit your format rules and select the **"All Cells Showing .... Values for ...."** option.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Do the followings:**

1. Select any cell of your PT, then Right click.
2. From poped up menu choose **PivotTable Options.**
3. Now, from the dialog box click **Layout & Format Tab.**
4. Check **Preserve cell formatting on update item** under the **Format** section.
5. Finish with **Ok,** & refresh the Pivot Table.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh unfortunately that option is already checked.

Comment: I updated the question accordingly

Comment: @jamiet thanks for the feedback,, this was the only possibility,,, is it possible to edit post & add GIF of the Sheet so I & others could find what is happening with the Sheet,,, principally my post is the solution !!