# How to make my PivotTable into a heatmap, persistently?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, heatmap

We can easily make an Excel table into a heatmap by applying a conditional formatting rule on the rectangle of relevant data cells. And - this can also be done for a PivotTable.

However, whenever you *update* the PivotTable - the conditional formatting rule is deleted (at least - in my experience).

How can I make my PivotTable be a heatmap, persistently?

Comment: Just noticed this is an effective dupe of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1464300/122798) - but that one doesn't have any answer which works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit the rule

Original Data and Pivot:

[image]

Here's what happens if you add a new type of fruit and refresh the pivot:

[image]

As you noted, the conditional formatting does not apply to the newly added row in the Pivot Table. The value of 5 for Berry is not formatted.

Let's edit the conditional format rule, changing the Apply To section to "All Cells showing Sum of Sales for Fruit".

[image]

Now add more data and refresh the pivot, and it works!

[image]