# How can I apply conditional formatting to rows that get added to a pivot table when new data is added? Specifically on MacOS

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, mac, conditional-formatting, pivot-table

The question is simple, and has been solved in multiple posts such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1464300/how-can-i-apply-conditional-formatting-to-rows-that-get-added-to-a-pivot-table-w) for PCs. Unfortunately on a Mac, that setting does not appear when editing the conditional formatting. This is how it looks on a Mac:

[image: This is how it looks on a Mac]

Any and all help is welcome, but no "just use a PC lol" replies please.

Comment: LibreOffice *Calc* (for Mac, as well as Windows and Linux) *might* have that option. *Calc* can edit and save in a few Excel file formats. It might be worthwhile testing - free to use.